# how to drag and drop images into textarea and view those images in that?

Tags: jquery

How can I drag and drop images into textarea and view those images in that?

```
<div class="form-group" id="textarea">                   
    <textarea id="textCompose"  class="form-control" style="height: 300px" name="message" placeholder="Message:"></textarea>                              
</div>
```

I have wrote queries to get images from database:

```
        $imagedisres=mysqli_query($db,$imagedisquery) or die(mysqli_error($db));?>
<div  id="divSource"> 
<div style="width:100%;">
  <?php while($row=@mysqli_fetch_array($imagedisres)){
    $image = $row['imagename'];
  ?>
  <div style="width:30%;float:left;min-height:100px;" align="center" align="middle"><img src="admin/upload/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="'.$title.'" style="width:90%;"></div>
<?php } ?>
</div></div>
```

Comment: use `draggable` and `dropable` area and then handle events

Comment: Can you describe how to write

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/ this will help you